QHBoxLayout not showing all the widgets
I´ m trying to code a simple chess stopwatch in Qt (2 buttons with a stopwatch on each, pressing one button activate the stopwatch of the other). I´ m using QHBoxLayout in order to have the 2 grouped together, this are the files so far
/*mainwindow.h*/

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "stopwatch.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    StopWatch* stopWatch_A;
    StopWatch* stopWatch_B;
    QPushButton* btnA;
    QPushButton* btnB;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

/*stopwatch.h*/

#ifndef STOPWATCH_H
#define STOPWATCH_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTime>

class StopWatch : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit StopWatch(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    QTime *time() const;

private slots:

    //to be implemented

private:

    QTime *m_time;
  
};

#endif // STOPWATCH_H

/*mainwindow.cpp*/

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    stopWatch_A = new StopWatch(this);
    stopWatch_B = new StopWatch(this);
    btnA = new QPushButton(stopWatch_A->time()->toString("mm:ss:z"), this);
    btnB = new QPushButton(stopWatch_B->time()->toString("mm:ss:z"), this);
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    layout->addWidget(btnA);
    layout->addWidget(btnB);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

/*stopwatch.cpp*/

#include "stopwatch.h"

StopWatch::StopWatch(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}
{

    m_time = new QTime(0,10,0);
}

QTime *StopWatch::time() const
{
    return m_time;
}

/*main.cpp*/

#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

When i compile and run the app in QtCreator the window shows only one button (the second added, in this case btnB)


QMainWindow has its own layout, as explained in the documentation, so the layout must be set on a central widget. Since you're using a Designer file, you already have a central widget in it: if it already has a layout, use it (do not try to replace it), otherwise set it with QHBoxLayout(ui->centralwidget).
